# MySQL INSERT with a Composite Key

Tags: mysql

Edit: I am a muppet. So after careful trawling of the rows I was trying to insert, there was a bug in my code which meant empty strings were being inserted. Because this happened more than once, MySQL quite rightly threw an error because I was trying to insert the same data again. Sorry for any time wasted! Mods, feel free to delete this.

My table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foo` (
  `user` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `group` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `completed` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`user`,`group`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Now when I try to do a MySQL Insert, it throws errors saying that I have duplicates (which with the key set up, won't work). What I don't get is why I am seeing those errors. I know that I am not inserting a duplicate of those composite values (although some values will appear many times in the group column.

An example of my insert: `INSERT INTO food(user, group, completed) VALUES ('user1', 'groupA', '0'),('user2', 'groupB', '0'),('user3', 'groupA', '0');`

So the composite of user and group are definitely unique. So why does it fail complaining that I am trying to insert a non unique key?

The error I get is: #1062 - Duplicate entry 'groupA' for key 1. It seems to be fine if I am trying to insert one or two rows at a time, but I am currently trying to insert 140 rows in one go.

Thanks!

Comment: Oh in case anyone is wondering, it's a "Duplicate Key Error" which is returned.

Comment: if you want to improve your question, use edit and not comment :o)

Comment: Did you check the table actually has the primary key defined as in your post?

Comment: and please post more reallife example that really show only your problem and not a bunch of failures, e.g. varchar(5) can only store 5 chars and "groupA" has 6 chars.

Comment: OK there are clearly a few errors. But I can assure you that they are not the problem. Basically I've just been obfuscating my DB with generic terms. Which has the side effect of no longer making complete sense.

Comment: @Jeroen Yes my table does (well that's certainly what PHPMyAdmin is telling me)

Comment: I run Your queries and no error except for what Sir Rufo mentioned about too short varchar.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use "group" as a column name because it's a reserved word.

I altered the column name and your query works just fine, as it should.

Since you've completely "obfuscated" your actual SQL, it's entirely possible that you edited out a typo that's responsible for your error.

Comment: Indeed group is a key word (but I think you can still use it if you use ``?). In fact I've obfuscated what I am actually doing by using the generic term `group`, but the column in my database is named differently.

Comment: You can use but You shouldn't. You have to remember to always put it between ticks if You do. Like this `group`.

Comment: Yep. But regardless, I'm definitely getting a different error. Will edit original post to include it.

Comment: I avoid reserved words; it's much better to be descriptive by saying a group of what...

Answer (score 0):

Your key is not composite. I fit was composite error would be like this

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'user1-groupA' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Notice, it displays values of all columns that make index.

I think You have another index just on column group.